# Can't choose the OS at startup

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu. My system already has Windows 7. I would like to keep the existing Windows installation. After installation of Ubuntu I restarted the PC, but there is no boot menu.
As per the opinion of the Linux team the following commands were used.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

The command executed correctly, but there is still no boot menu. What do I have to do?

Please help me.

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the caps.. Please check before posting if your *Caps Lock* is on.. ;)

Comment: @SirCharlo I still see it in all caps...

Comment: Commented before actually editing :P

Comment: WELL READING SOMETHING IN ALL CAPS IS USUALLY QUITE ANNOYING, SO TO HELP YOU GET MORE HELP I THOUGHT IT WOULD BE APPROPRIATE TO DO SO!!!!

Comment: can you help me through any remote desktop management software

Comment: About your problem, did your wipe your hard drive, or did you choose the option to keep the existing Windows installation when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: I choose the option keep the existing windows installation. in my pc there is 4 partition . i like to install ubuntu , keeping windows7

Comment: Please provide more details about the installation. Did you install Ubuntu along side Windows, or did you replace Windows during installation? If you have replaced Windows by mistake, and Ubuntu is the only operating system, grub menu does not display. @SirCharlo said it before me. The last comment makes me believe that this may be 4 existing primary partition issue, rather than grub issue.

Comment: how did you set up your harddisk(s)? Are you using different ones for ubuntu and windows?

Comment: nstall Ubuntu along side Windows,during installation the option was install ubuntu inside windows. now my pc have windows7, i like to keep it

Comment: Everyone, let's discuss this in [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4154/help-for-anilkumar)

Comment: Please provide more information. What make and model of computer is it? Can you find out if all of the 4 partitions are **Primary** partitions? One way to to do this is to boot from Live CD and use the "Try Ubuntu" option. Then run "gparted" to see what kind of partitions you have. Do not edit or delete partitions yet, unless you are 100% sure it will not harm your computer.

Comment: Please ask a new question about the remote management software.

Answer (score 4):

### Try to show the Grub menu

Hold down the
   <kbd>Shift</kbd> key as the computer attempts to boot to display the GRUB 2
   menu. In certain circumstances, if holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key method does
   not display the menu pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key repeatedly may display the
   menu.

---

If that doesn't work, then using Boot Repair to reinstall and fix Grub.

### Boot Repair

#### Repair the bootloader

To restore the Grub bootloader, follow these steps.

Open a terminal, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

#### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running by now.

Answer (score 2):

- Boot a live cd
- Mount the partition where you want to install GRUB, likely it's the partition where Ubuntu is installed

open a terminal and run this command

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX --root-directory=/where/ubuntu/is/mounted
```

choose the X and the right path according to your configuration.

You do **not** have to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

after `grub-install` just reboot.

Comment: what you mean   by"Mount the partition where you want to install GRUB,"  i have no experience in ubuntu

Comment: Your answer is too complex, please delete it or clarify it for inexperienced users.. Thank you!

Comment: i tried it but no result, there is no boot repair window opened

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair   ////////// no result

Answer (score 0):

- Download [Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)
- burn it on a CD or make a liveUSB
- Boot on it
- Click `Recommended Repair`
- Write the URL on a paper
- Reboot
- If still not good, indicate the URL